# Video Editing: Masking Problem

Tags: video-sequence-editor, masking

I'm a complete beginner with Blender and would greatly appreciate any help with the problem described below. Thanks in advance.

I would like to create a video sequence in which text scrolls vertically over part of a background image. The background image contains a box. I want the text to appear only within the bounds of this box.

Over the top of the background image, I add a text box in a new channel and use keyframes to animate it. When I scrub through the video, the text animates but, of course, it scrolls over the whole image.

In a new channel, above the text channel, I create a copy of the background image to use as a mask. To this I add an adjustment layer mask. The mask is positioned over the box in the image and then inverted, so that the box is the only part of the mask that is transparent.

Now, when I scrub through the video, the text only appears when it's within the bounds of the box (great) but nothing but the box area is rendered (not great). Everything surrounding the box displays the chequerboard pattern.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. As I said above, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Hello and welcome to https://blender.stackexchange.com/! Usually it helps to understand a question better and avoid misunderstandings by adding pictures that outline your problem. In some cases it can also be helpful if you additionally share your blend file on https://blend-exchange.com. This way you help others to answer your question faster. Thank you!

Comment: so you want this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G4jx.gif

Comment: Thank you, yes. Actually, I've figured out a solution. I edited my overlay image, so it had proper transparency in the required region and used it as a mask channel. If (when) I post a question in future, I'll add pics and blend files. Thanks again.